# Django sending chunked responses

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi, django-wsgi

My setup is Django->Gunicorn->Nginx

Although I don't use `HttpStreamingResponse`, browser sees `Transfer-encoding: chunked` This causes problems with Cloudfront (it doesn't autocompress chunked responses)

My gunicorn runs with default values, so default worker etc. and I couldn't find any option in nginx regarding this.

Should I stop using chunked? If so how?

I found this https://github.com/abrookins/streaming_django which mentions

```
First, some conditions must be true:

- The client must be speaking HTTP/1.1 or newer
- The request method wasn't a HEAD
- The response does not include a Content-Length header
- The response status wasn't 204 or 304

If these conditions are true, then Gunicorn will add a Transfer-Encoding: chunked header to the response, signaling to the client that the response will stream in chunks.

In fact, Gunicorn will respond with Transfer-Encoding: chunked even if you used an HttpResponse, if those conditions are true!
```

but does it mean I should go to each view and add my content-length? Is my Django failing to do this?